Berge's Maximum Theorem for Parameters that are Functions
I am given some functions $f_i$ that are $C^1$, $f_i : \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ and some budget $z \in \mathbb{R}_+$. I have some constrained optimization problem with a continuous objective function $F$, and want to show the maximization problem is continuous in $z$.
I know that Berge's Maximum Theorem applies when the set of parameters $\Theta \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, but in this case my parameters are functions. I was wondering if there is some sort of analogue for functional parameters, or if there are any references to explore as I couldn't find much.
